# Размер блока css

Tags: css

Как изменить положение и размер блока?
Вот допустим есть у меня горизонтальный блок менюшки, по умолчанию он находится сверху справа сайта. Через паддинг переместил его под заголовок и в середину, ну и разумеется размер блока идет из того изначального угла. Нужно чтобы блок занимал горизонтальную полоску только где кнопки меню, чтобы фон покрасить ему. Как это сделать?

Comment: Добавьте Вашу разметку, что Вы уже сделали

Answer (score -1):

не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

я попробую написать то, что понял, возможно вам это поможет
css+html:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;  /* наша шапка */
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;  /* наше меню */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">Шапка сайта</div> <!-- шапка -->
    <div class="menu">блок с меню</div>   <!-- меню -->
</body>
</html>
```